# Make multiple attempts to call the ajax web service in case of error

Tags: wcf, jquery

I am calling a web service using jquery $.ajax() function. In case of error in the web service call i need to call the web service 2 more time.

How should be the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a past project I just used Settimeout to check for empty returned results fromthe Ajax call.... so for instance

```
var failcounter = 0;

if (CHECK SOME CONDITION HERE FOR RESULTS  && failcounter < 4){
    //IF FOUND TO BE EMPTY THEN WE ADD ONE TO THE 'COUNTER' THEN USE SETTIMEOUT TO RE-TRY...
        setTimeout(function () {
            failcounter++;
            yourajaxFunctioncall();
      }, 5000);
};
```

this is really rough and just tossed together - not all all meant to work from cut/paste since I haven't seen your code - but hopefully you get the idea, use a 'counter' to keep track of an limit the number of times its re-tried...   if NO RESULTS are found use settimeout to re-try it again.    I've also used Ajax 'error:' (similar to 'success:') to hold specific functions to try upon fail - so that may be easier -- just depends on how you want to handle I guess. good luck